# Rename site from "Software Quality Assurance and Testing" to "SQA"

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Just a suggestion:  Rename site from "Software Quality Assurance and Testing" to "SQA" .  Other shorter names might also work.

The reasoning being that the site name would therefore fit nicely into the bottom of the "StackOverflow" site.   It is likely that this site would never earn a place in that footer unless the name is shortened.

If you agree, vote this question up.

Comment: I assume also you are happy for us to vote down if we disagree?

Comment: I have to admit that while I do disagree as indicated by my answer, I find the enthusiasm to make the site better encouraging. I also find the idea itself to be a "Think-Outside-the-Box" idea, which may indeed lead further ideas I do agree with.

Comment: The criteria for what makes a site eligible to graduate from beta are a combination of several factors, but I can tell you with certainty that the length of the site's title is not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Two points: rpg.stackexchange is in the main site's footer as 'rpg' despite being named Role-playing Games:

[image]

So if we make it into that footer, chances are high it will get shortened.

In the meantime, if we want to make it into that footer any time soon, I feel we are far better off promoting the site, sharing questions, continuing to seed the site with good solid content, and editing the existing content to an expert level than we are giving it a new name.